# Does saying "thank you" in an informative comment invalidate the entire comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Specifically, I made the following comment on [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899347/238419):

> @Eric: Most teams would not have the enthusiasm/bravery to do this, choosing instead to hide behind, *"Sorry, can't, breaking change etc., it's broken forever."* So **thank you** for having the courage to make a breaking-improvement!

It got a lot of upvotes (~80?), so at least one other person thought it was justified; but it was deleted by a mod *(casperOne)* for *"being too chatty."*

I know I enjoy the rare *"thank you"* when I help someone out - are these comments really not allowed?

Comment: Ok, so who uploaded that question to facebook? Tons of views and votes, wow.

Comment: Just to let you know, your comment got way over 100 votes. I was going to vote it up after seeing it on my mobile browser but I was logged out...

Comment: Just in case we're somehow under the delusion that highly upvoted comments are *good*: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59609/new

Comment: My guideline for deleting off-topic comments is to try to arrange that all on-topic comments are visible under the post without clicking on “show N more comments”. As I write, there are 5 visible comments, and more than 5 comments that are useful by dint of providing extra information or clarifications. Since your comment was off-topic, I would have given it the ax in favor of the more useful ones. The number of upvotes, if anything, speak for deletion because the most-upvoted comments are shown in priority.

Comment: Note that this wasn't thanking for a correct answer, but for adding a feature to the C# compiler.

Comment: This is not a duplicate; it was not my question, and my comment was more than a one-word 'thanks.'  I wonder, **if I hadn't said thank you**, would the comment still have been deleted?

Comment: @BlueRaja Was any part of the comment useful for future visitors? That's really the only question you need to ask. People reading that post in the future don't care about how courageous you think the C# team is

Comment: The entire comment was one long thank you

Comment: We had no fun and no gratitude, add no encouragement.  Don't forget to delete the upvoted comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8870593/17034  As long as "why do you want to know that" is on topic anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Saying "thank you" as part of a comment that clarifies something or add a bit of information ripe for rolling into the main post doesn't invalidate the entire comment.

Stretching out a thank you to be a complete paragraph, or long enough sentence to get around the minimum character rule, adds nothing more than visible glad-handing.

Rule of thumb is that if you can remove the part that is gushing all over the place and have the comment still impart a nugget of information, then it can stand. But there is no need to effuse or seal clap, so just lop that wart off.

If the quoted comment hadn't said thank you, it wouldn't exist at all. The entire thing is one long thank you muchly.